# Access text recognized by Acrobat OCR

Tags: c#, pdf, ocr

I have PDF files that have been "recognized" using the **OCR Text Recognition -> Recognize Text Using OCR** functionality in Acrobat.

I would like to take these as an upload (C# ASP.NET MVC) and be able to extract this information for indexing and search purposes.

I have tried opening the PDF files and I don't find any of the recognized text so I'm guessing it's compressed and/or encoded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- There is an article on CodeProject that explains how you can [extract text from PDF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/pdf2text.aspx) using C#.
- [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/) and [poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) have `pdftotext` tools.